# Tomtom route api routeType parameter not working

Tags: tomtom

I am running the TomTom route api.

This is the url.

https://api.tomtom.com/routing/1/calculateRoute/7.841327000000001,6.745921000000001:7.840205322,6.746850516?key=mykey>&routeType=fastest

The distance shows 176 meters.

When i run the same api changing the **routeType = 'thrilling'**, as shown below

https://api.tomtom.com/routing/1/calculateRoute/7.841327000000001,6.745921000000001:7.840205322,6.746850516?key=mykey>&routeType=thrilling

I still get the same distancee of **176 mtr**

But the GUI website for tomtom route shows different results.

I looked for the route between same coordinates on the Tomtom GUI for route.

First: (fastest)

https://mydrive.tomtom.com/en_gb/#mode=routes+viewport=7.84061,6.74596,17.97,0,-0+routes=%7B%22departure%22:true,%22traffic%22:true,%22routeType%22:%22FASTEST%22,%22travelMode%22:%22CAR%22,%22points%22:%5B%22hw~7.84132,6.74592~A~Kogi,%20NGA%22,%22hw~7.8402,6.74685~A~Kogi,%20NGA%22%5D,%22avoidCriteria%22:%5B%5D%7D+ver=3

I got distance as 190 yards

Second: (thrill)

https://mydrive.tomtom.com/en_gb/#mode=routes+viewport=7.83847,6.74261,15.93,0,-0+routes=%7B%22roundTrip%22:true,%22departure%22:true,%22traffic%22:true,%22routeType%22:%22THRILLING%22,%22travelMode%22:%22CAR%22,%22hilliness%22:%22NORMAL%22,%22windingness%22:%22NORMAL%22,%22points%22:%5B%22hw~7.84132,6.74592~A~Kogi,%20NGA%22,%22hw~7.8402,6.74685~A~Kogi,%20NGA%22%5D,%22avoidCriteria%22:%5B%22ALREADY_USED_ROADS%22%5D%7D+ver=3

I got distance as 3 miles.

My main concern is it is showing correct results while using **mydrive.tomtom.com** , but through API, the **routeType** option is **not working**.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

1. In the second link you have selected "Rount trip". If you deselect it then you have the same result. But if you want to achieve simmilar result via API call then just copy first point and add after colon as a third point.
2. It is hard to get different results with such short distance.